# Can I get/access a form_builder.object's ATTRIBUTE in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have resorted to ask a question here since this is something that's puzzling me:

I am trying to create a nested attributes form with the following models:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredient_records, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :recipe    
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_records, allow_destroy: true

class IngredientRecord < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food, inverse_of: :ingredient_records
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :ingredient_records
```

I've ommited some parts of the models that are non related. (At least I hope so).

The main problem comes here: When I do this on the :edit view:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :food_id %>
    <%= f.select :food_id, [[ f.object.food, f.object.food_id ]]%>
```

It outputs a select field with an option like <#Food:x0203400291> (the form_builder object, verified it's the correct object with a breakpoint with byebug)

BUT when I do (it's the **.name** part):

```
<%= f.select :food_id, [[ f.object.food.name, f.object.food_id ]]%>
```

Rails raises an error screen with: `undefined method ´name' for nil:NilClass` (name is an attribute on the Food.model).

What do you guys think? Am I actually tryin something that's **not allowed inside a rails view**? (Would be strange since putting a byebug clause just before the select builder and calling `f.object.food.name` returns the value just fine). Thanks in advance!

Comment: `f.object.food&.name` would 99% solve it (or `f.object.food.try(:name)` if you're on Ruby < 2.3).

Comment: That's a good workaround, thanks. Still puzzles me why such a call to an attribute would raise an error.